# What causes error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not find assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke...'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

The full error information is

**Code**: MC1000

**Description**: Unknown build error, 'Could not find assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Either explicitly load this assembly using a method such as LoadFromAssemblyPath() or use a MetadataAssemblyResolver that returns a valid assembly.'

**File**: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.WinFX.targets 243

I'll provide a little context in case it's helpful. This is in a .NET Core 3.0 WPF project, that references a .NET Core 3.0 Console App, that references a .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library. All levels except the top level WPF project also reference a slew of Nuget packages, most of which are probably targeting .NET Standard 1.3 or 2.0. They are all targeting a compatible .NET Standard, I don't have any that are throwing the [NU1701 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1701).

So the question: what is causing this error?

Comment: Open package manager up for nuget and run `Install-Package System.Runtime.InteropServices -Version 4.3.0`.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That was my first idea too, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok how about `Install-Package System.Runtime.InteropServices.PInvoke -Version 4.0.0-rc3-24117-00 -Source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json` maybe just missing the PInvoke...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The exact command didn't work, but a closely related one did. When I ran yours it told me it wouldn't respect the Source parameter, and that it couldn't find that version in my existing sources, but that it found a version 4.0.0-rc2-24027 on nuget.org. So I installed that one and it fixed the issue. That package is unlisted, which makes it very hard to find in the Visual Studio GUI or the nuget website, which is why I didn't find it before. Do you have any guesses at a minimal repro? Seems like this is probably a build system bug.

Comment: glad you found a good version then, I wasn't sure about that version I even listed TBH. MS is bad about adding dependencies to their packages, I just helped another user yesterday with similar issue. I knew you were missing either the Interop and or PInvoke namespaces, wasn't quite sure from that error. Also I believe MS doesn't include these dependencies by default, unless you need them, either another library expects them etc... On another note anything with `rc` in the package are not guaranteed to be good, they are just that, pre-release...